# Unable to get contents of div and meta tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the content within div and meta tag of a website using .get_text() method after find_all method as shown in the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
#skipped some lines
names = bs_obj.find_all("div", {'class':'classname'})
for name in names:
    print(name.get_text()+"\n")
```

Let's say the contents of div tags are

```
<div class="classname">content1</div>
<div class="classname">content2</div>
```

My expected result is

```
content1
content2
```

However the actual output is

```
<div class="classname">content1</div>
<div class="classname">content2</div>
```

I have tried some methods like `split()`,`replace()`,`re.search()` but the tags won't disappear. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: which version of beautifulsoup are you using?

Comment: I'm using bs4 perhaps I should show the import line

Answer (score 1):

You almost got the result:

```py
html_doc = """ 
<div class="classname">content1</div> 
<div class="classname">content2</div> 
""" 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
bs_obj = soup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

names = bs_obj.findAll('div', {'class':'classname'})

for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: The original poster uses the `.find_all()` method which is for Beautifulsoup <v4, your answer is making use of the `.findAll()` method which is for Beautifulsoup >=v4. Are you sure you are correctly providing a solution?

Comment: Actually I'm using v4 and I tried `find_all()`, `findAll()`, `.text`, `getText()` and `get_text()` but none of them work

Comment: It works if you form it like this: `names = bs_obj.find_all('div', class_='classname')`.